# Is there a name for `if __name__ == '__main__':` idiom?

Tags: python

Just looking to see if there's any name for the idiom. Looking for a simple thing to call this.

Comment: I don't know. If you want a short name call it "`__main__` guard" (pronounced the same as "main guard" in speech).

Comment: need more clarity tho

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html

Comment: FWIW I'm only a novice coder but I call it "if name equals main"

Comment: I'm not looking to invent a short hand or name for the idiom, was just looking if one existed. I think the answer is no.